# What happens when I die or go back to the Void ship?

Tags: void-bastards

I'm unclear on what I actually lose when I die or choose to return to the Void ship (e.g., handing in the Citizen Card)?

- Do I lose my progress on the map or do I respawn where I was?
- I know I keep the items I have constructed, but do I keep parts and the materials that can make parts (bio, plaz, etc.)?
- What happens to Merits, torpedos, fuel, food? If I only keep a percentage, how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the devs,

> **[What items are kept or lost when I die?](https://steamcommunity.com/app/857980/discussions/0/1643164649202991625/)** You lose all ammo, food, fuel, merits, torpedoes and warp keys when you die, however, you will
>   keep all parts, materials and upgrades you have built on the
>   workbench. Note that if you die while on board a ship you lose
>   anything you picked up in that ship too.